# Compare 2 images appium

Tags: android, selenium, imageview, appium

I would like to know if it's possible to compare 2 ImageView and see if they are the same or not with appium.

I have a list of small pictures on the bottom of the screen and by clicking one of them the selected one is shown in the middle of the screen.

Is it possible to test that by clicking on another in the list the central image did change ?

Thank you

Comment: what you want to do??

Comment: Compare 2 ImageView and see if they are the same or not

Comment: it is only be byimage processing

Comment: is there any unique property that changes with image selection? - e.g. id, name, or anything. Appium does not support image comparison.

Comment: No they have they are the same in UIAutomatorViewer the old central image is replaced by the new one with the same properties

Comment: you can get image height,width and size and also other parameter by which you can diffrentiate two images.

Comment: its call image processing my friend